# Raspberry Pi simulator supporting Python websocket library

Tags: python, websocket, raspberry-pi, cryptography, simulator

I have a python code representing a websocket client and performing a given number of cryptographic operations (with library hashlib, cryptography, ect...). I would like to run it on a Raspberry Pi simulator to assess its capacity to be run on a more resource constained device. Does anyone know of anything that might work?

I saw that the version of Wyliodrin STUDIO does not support Python yet and didn't find information about others. I know that micropython exists, but can I use it on a simulator and does it support those specific python libraries?

Comment: A recent Raspberry Pi is a full featured multi-core, multi-GHz and multi-GB RAM computer. So, I'm wondering what you expect to test? And BTW there are multiple way on Linux to restrict the use of system resources.